# Replacing #text elements with spans causes documents to reshape

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to replace every #text that has siblings with spans so that they have ids. The following code is supposed to do this, but for some reason it causes many documents to reshape: parts of the document move, page changes its appearance.

```
var eltId = 0;

function genEltId() {
    return "my-id-" + ++eltId;
}

function hashTextsToSpans(elt) {
    for (var i in elt.childNodes) {
        var eltChild = elt.childNodes[i];
        if (eltChild.nodeName == "#text" && elt.childNodes.length > 1) {
            // #text is one of multiple childs
            var eltDiv = document.createElement("span");
            eltDiv.setAttribute("id", genEltId());
            elt.replaceChild(eltDiv, eltChild);
            eltDiv.appendChild(eltChild);
        } else {
            if (eltChild.nodeName != "IFRAME") {
                hashTextsToSpans(eltChild);
            }
        }
    }
}

function onKeyPress(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 105) {
        // key I
        hashTextsToSpans(document.body);
    }
}

window.parent.addEventListener("keypress", onKeyPress);
```

For example, inject it in chrome (using "cjs" addon) into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux , press "i", and observe that the page reshapes.

What is the problem? Aren't #text and span both inline elements, and should be displayed in the same way when the text is the same and span has no style?

Assumptions: no iframe elements, no other javascript that manipulates the DOM tree at the same time.

Comment: are you using any css frameworks?

Comment: no frameworks, I am injecting js into wikipedia as an example with "cjs" addon.

Comment: Not an answer, but you may want to look into the [`TreeWalker` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker), which is available in all modern browsers and makes this task a lot easier to code and maintain.

Comment: @rvighne Thanks for the TreeWalker reference, I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in HTML, many elements have restrictions on what types of child nodes they are allowed to contain.

For example, list elements (e.g. `ul` or `ol`) can only contain `li` elements and blank (whitespace-only) text nodes. When you wrap such blank text nodes in spans, suddenly the page is non-standards-compliant.

In the specific case of the Wikipedia page you linked to, the original page had text nodes containing only whitespace *between* the `tr` and `td` elements of a table. When your script runs, those text nodes become spans, but it is not allowed to have elements outside of `tr` and `td` elements within a table. Thus, this causes most browsers to automatically insert phantom columns into the table, messing up the layout.

As a quick fix, you could ignore text nodes that contain only whitespace. This is trivial to do if you use the TreeWalker API, by passing in the following function as a filter:

```
node => /\S/.test(node.nodeValue) ? NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT : NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT
```

As a more long-term fix, you'll probably need to look through the [HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) to know for sure which elements are allowed to contain span nodes, and write your script accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is correct! By excluding TABLE/TBODY/TR/UL/OL parent elements the problem is gone. Thanks again!